# Team explorer default resolve in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I am getting annoyed by having to change Resolve to Associate in Team Explorer

[image]

Is there a way to set it to Associate by default?

Comment: not as far as I'm aware, this has been there since 2012, many requests have been made to MS to alter this, there did used to be a registry hack to fix it but this was only for 2012. This guy seem to have a work around, but i have not tested or investigated this.  http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Changing-the-Default-CheckIn-Option-to-Associate-in-TFS-2012.aspx

Comment: Why did your code not resolve the task?

Comment: @MrHinsh cause one normally codes in small bits in TDD by passing a few tests and the moment they are done you want to push them to prevent possible conflicts but they do not resolve full task.

Comment: I use Git locally for that. Then the only association is on a Push...

Comment: And when one codes in small bits in TDD one does not CheckIn to the server untill one is ready to share code with a wider audience. :) I would only ever checkin to the server when a task is resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For visual studio 2013 this fixes the issue

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior] 
"ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="False"

Answer (score 2):

And now available in the settings UI in Visual Studio 2015: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3418758-in-the-team-explorer-change-default-state-value-o

Answer (score 2):

### Visual Studio 2019

I came here seeking an answer for VS 2019, as apparently the registry 'hack' no longer works.

There is now an setting in `Tools -> Options` for this, under `Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` called `Resolve associated work items on check-in`.

Un-check it to associate by default. Check to resolve by default.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Options Associate/Resolve]