# Default action for a TFS task on check-in does not stick

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

As has adequately been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159165/team-explorer-default-resolve-in-vs2013) and elsewhere, it is possible to change the default action to Resolve or Associate on check-in.

However, whenever I set this value to False, it eventually changes back to True. Presumably something somewhere is overwriting this - but what?

Comment: How long will it change back to True? Are you using the same VS on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, always the same machine.

Comment: Could you let us know how long will the value change back to True? I'd like to have a test on my side.

Comment: I shall try and measure this but I don't check in every day. I've also tried a reboot to see if this causes it (I usually leave my machine on overnight) but this didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The value of ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction has been set to False for two days on my side, and the value is still False. I couldn't reproduce your scenario on my side. You may monitor your issue to see whether it happens regularly and post back, so that we can investigate the root cause together.

Comment: Mine reverted back to True as of yesterday and I have set it back to False so we shall see how long the setting sticks.

Comment: As an alternative, to prevent registry keys changed, you can set permissions for registry keys. see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728310(v=ws.10).aspx. Please make sure you backup your system before you try anything.

Answer (score 0):

By default (`ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="True"`), when you add a "**Task**" work item type to the Related Work Items under Pending Changes, the action is "**Resolved**". But when you add other work item types (not "Task"), the action will be "**Associate**".

After changing the `ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="False"` (`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior] "ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="False"`), any work item types, including "**Task**" that add to Related Work Items, the action is "**Associate**".

This setting is only working on client side. If you change the client machine or change the VS version, you have to reset `ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="False"`.